# Find total number of rows using data from 3 tables, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, distinct

I'm trying to return a number but the query needs to cover 3 tables, I think!
here's a quick example of how the 3 tables are (with a few columns chopped off)

```
table: opencall
---------------------------------
Users name | Site  | Phone      |
---------------------------------
John Smith | Leeds | 0113 1234567

table: userdb
-------------------------------------
emailAd         | site  | company   |
-------------------------------------
user@domain.com | Leeds | Yorks Post

table: company
----------------------------
pk_company_id  | division_name |
----------------------------
Yorks Post     | NORTH
```

Now, what I'm trying to do is find the total number of rows in opencall where the "division_name" is "NORTH", I've tried a few queries, but they always come back with a number too big.

here's an example of what I've tried:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM opencall, company, userdb WHERE userdb.site = opencall.site AND userdb.company = company.pk_company_id AND opencall.logdatex BETWEEN 1385041200 and 1388041200 AND opencall.condition NOT IN (8,9,11,12,19) AND company.division_name = 'NORTH`'
```

however, this returns a result of over 8,000, where as if I just put:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM opencall where logdatex BETWEEN 1385041200 and 1388041200 AND condition NOT IN (8,9,11,12,19)
```

this returns 128 so the number I'm after when limiting the division_name should be around 20. Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT oc.UsersName)
FROM opencall oc 
INNER JOIN userdb u ON oc.site = u.site
INNER JOIN company c ON u.company = c.pk_company_id
WHERE c.division_name = 'NORTH'AND oc.logdatex BETWEEN 1385041200 AND 1388041200 AND 
      oc.condition NOT IN (8,9,11,12,19)
```

Comment: Thank you! works perfectly, since I'm still learning, I understand it all except the distinct bit, can you explain what that is doing?

Comment: @Maff You're most welcome. I had just added `COUNT(DISTINCT oc.UsersName)` instead of `COUNT(*)` because of we want to find the total number of users in specific division.  So I had counted distinct users from `opencall` table

Answer (score 0):

Your data structure is messed up.  There is no link between company and division.  You can create one from `userdb` by using aggregation.  I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM (select distinct site, company
      from userdb u
     ) u join
     opencall o
     on u.site = o.site join
     company c
     on u.company = c.pk_company_id
WHERE o.logdatex BETWEEN 1385041200 and 1388041200 AND
      o.condition NOT IN (8,9,11,12,19) AND
      c.division_name = 'NORTH`;
```

Comment: I receive this error, I cannot figure out, where it's incorrect though - You have an error in your SQL syntax.  Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select distinct site, company
      from useredb u
     ) u j

Comment: @Maff . . . `userdb` was misspelled.